# Automatically refreshing a listbox or datagrid bound to an arraylist?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, binding, listbox

I am working with a Windows Forms application binding a listbox to an arraylist using techniques as described in these [two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.aspx) [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0wfd4yz.aspx).

```
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "LongName";
ListBox1.ValueMember = "ShortName";
```

or for datagridview

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = customers;
```

In WPF you are able to bind to an observable collection and the grid will be automatically updated when there are changes to the list. But I cannot seem to replicate this in windows forms.

Is there something I am missing, or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "two-way" binding in Windows Forms, you need to use a collection that implements [IBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx).

There is some helpful information in [this article](http://www.freeweb.hu/noiseehc/ulrich.html).

Comment: Searching for hours yielded only awful examples. In five minutes you set me on the correct path. Thank you.